# How to pass path arguments to java on macOS

Tags: java, macos, terminal

How should I pass paths to the jvm on macOS?
I'm trying to run [this command](https://pastebin.com/PLmNuV4T) but it doesn't work since the syntax is wrong (the same command works on windows with obviously different libraries).
Thank you for your help!

Full command:

```
java  -Djava.library.path=/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/natives -cp /Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/authlib-1.5.25.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/codecjorbis-20101023.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/codecwav-20101023.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/commons-codec-1.10.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/commons-io-2.5.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/commons-lang3-3.5.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/fastutil-7.1.0.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/gson-2.8.0.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/guava-21.0.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/httpclient-4.3.3.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/httpcore-4.3.2.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/jinput-2.0.5.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/jna-4.4.0.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/jutils-1.0.0.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/oshi-core-1.1.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/patchy-1.1.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/platform-3.4.0.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/realms-1.10.22.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/soundsystem-20120107.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/text2speech-1.10.3-natives-windows.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/bin/text2speech-1.10.3.jar;/Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/cores/1.12.2.jar -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=32m net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username tigierrei --version 1.12.2 --gameDir /Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2 --assetsDir /Users/filippocavallari/Documents/SoulNetworkLauncher/modpacks/Vanilla1.12.2/assets --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid 2842ec6ea599466298472a1edbb9619b --accessToken 84a4b1eb01f4449cb47257d8c3123259 --userProperties {} --userType mojang
```

Comment: Use `:` as path separator on Unix and macOS, instead of `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JB Nizer said, you have to use : instead of ; to separate paths